# Duplicate the result set of a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I want to average out values of a specific query based on the weekday of the date in the table, and duplicate it for the other days. I know that this explanation was confusing, see the example below.

```
Eg:- Table Structure - 
ID, Value, Date

Expected Result-
Avg(value), Weekname(day)
12.23    , Mon
12.23    , Tue
12.23    , Wed
12.23    , Thu
12.23    , Fri
34.56    , Sat
56.34    , Sun
```

Ie, values for Monday - Friday is the same.

```
Current Result
Avg(value), Weekname(day)
12.23    , Mon
34.56    , Sat
56.34    , Sun
```

The query looks like this -

```
select avg(value)
      ,daynameofweek(date) 
from table
group by (CASE WHEN  DAYOFWEEK(DATE) NOT BETWEEN 2 and 6 THEN DAYOFWEEK(DATE) END)
```

Thanks for the help, in Advance.

#### Edit - Adding example data set

```
ID  Value   Date
1   2.500   2017-01-01
2   0.674   2017-01-02
3   2.743   2017-01-03
4   1.460   2017-01-04
5   1.457   2017-01-05
6   1.791   2017-01-06
7   1.896   2017-01-07
8   2.015   2017-01-08
9   2.224   2017-01-09
10  1.635   2017-01-10
11  1.100   2017-01-11
12  0.441   2017-01-12
13  0.809   2017-01-13
14  1.508   2017-01-14
```

Expected Result

```
Avg(Value)  daynameofweek(date) 
1.625   Monday
1.625   Tuesday
1.625   Wednesday
1.625   Thursday
1.625   Friday
1.300   Saturday
1.702   Sunday
```

Comment: Please include sample data set and table definition in your post

Comment: Why 2 and 6 ? What is the logic behind that? Copy the values until the gaps ends? Please rephrase the question .

Comment: 2 refers to weekday of Monday and 6 is Friday.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid sample data set has been added to the post.

Comment: The sample data set doesn't really seem to relate to the original question

Comment: In your original expected result you wanted the Monday value copied to Tuesday to Friday. In your new result you have different values for these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing that you end up with 'MON' for Monday to Friday, but this is arbitrarily chosen by the DBMS and you could just as well end up with, say, 'WED', because this day too is in the grouped-by range. So start with getting a determinate value here. Then join with a made-up day table:

```
select
  days.dayname,
  data.avg_value
from
(
  select 
    case when dayofweek(date) between 2 and 6 then 2 else dayofweek(date) end as day
    avg(value) as avg_value
  from table
  group by case when dayofweek(date) between 2 and 6 then 2 else dayofweek(date) end
) data
join
(
  select 1 as day, 'SUN' as dayname, 7 as sortkey union all
  select 2 as day, 'MON' as dayname, 1 as sortkey union all
  select 2 as day, 'TUE' as dayname, 2 as sortkey union all
  select 2 as day, 'WED' as dayname, 3 as sortkey union all
  select 2 as day, 'THU' as dayname, 4 as sortkey union all
  select 2 as day, 'FRI' as dayname, 5 as sortkey union all
  select 7 as day, 'SAT' as dayname, 6 as sortkey
) days on days.day = data.day
order by data.sortkey;
```

(If I remember correctly, MySQL allows to group by the alias name (`group by day`), which is not standard compliant. Use this, if you like it better.)